# Index Filtrado MVC C#

Tags: index

espero me puedan dar una Luz con este tema, resulta que estoy trabajando en asp.net core con pages razor MVC, tengo un Controller en donde se genera el index principal  (con su crud), deseo que al clickear en Módulos, me traiga solo los datos por el id del proyecto, no todos los módulos de todos los proyectos(datos) registrados, veo que en la mayoría de casos ese espacio es para editar, y eliminar registros por que se maneja el {id = item.id}, no para redireccionar a un index y filtrarlo en el controller, agradezco cualquier ayuda. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el filtro que uso en el controlador

```
private object requerimientos_Modulo;

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    private DataTable mod(int IdMod)
    {
        //medtodo que filtra los datos
        string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServices"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(con))
        {
            // return datos
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Requerimientos_Modulo WHERE IdMod = Id"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter rst = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", IdMod);  // 
                    cmd.Connection = cnn;
                    rst.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable tbl = new DataTable())
                    {
                        tbl.TableName = "Requerimientos_Modulo";
                        rst.Fill(tbl);
                        /*return dt;*/
                        return View(requerimientos_Modulo.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private DataTable View(object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué te parece si editas la pregunta e incluyes todo el código referente a lo que has realizado y lo que has intentado? ¿Consideras que si lo haces, aumentas las chances de respuesta?